# How to upgrate axios in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i dont use from axios in my project but I got the following error :

Upgrade axios to version 0.21.1 or later. For example:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "axios": ">=0.21.1"
}
```

now my axios version in package.json file is `"axios": "^0.19",` and my laravel version in 5.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `npm update axios` to update it to the latest version

or you can use `npm i axios@0.21.1 --save-dev` for update to a specific version